# Compilation Error While Launching Asp.Net Web Project From Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, webforms, codepages

I have created a Web Project in vs2019 and then after a month I have migrated it on vs2022. Therefore I have to upgrade all the references dll used in the project. After that it is builded perfectly and launched without any error. But today when I have opened it and launched, it shows be `Compilation Error` regarding `System.Text.Encoding.CopePages`. I am not using this library at all and not even included in project but don't know why today after launching, it has started to target this library.

**Error Message:**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0
```

Unable to trace this error. I have not used the following library the error is showing for, but still it giving me error for this library. Then I have installed the latest stable version of this library but still I am getting this error. How should I resolve it ?